# HTML Documentation for private repos?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a few Bitbucket private repos which I would like to document using read-the-docs or Sphinx. It looks like RTD requires a public repository which I can't do.

What's the best option to have a cool HTML documentation linked to Bitbucket, but which only myself and a few people of my choosing can actually view?

Comment: Since you want to publicly publish your documentation on Read-The-Doc, you can create a project on GitHub which will contains only your documentation: a kind of Sphinx project.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Sphinx to build your docs and commit them to the project's or a separate repository under your organization. With a separate repository, you could control access to it.

There is a paid [commercial version of RTD](https://readthedocs.com/), too.